# Type of terminal/connector to use for CAN bus on Arduino MKR CAN Shield

Tags: connector, can, terminal

Probably, this is obvious to everyone, but since I am a newbie to electrical engineering I am stuck. I have two wires of a CAN bus, (CANL and CANH), and I wish to connect them to the [Arduino MKR CAN shield](https://store.arduino.cc/mkr-can-shield).

[image]

Which types of connectors do I need to buy and then crimp to the end of my cables in order to make this connection? I cannot seem to find any documentation as to which terminal is used on that shield. I suppose the terminal is the green one to the left of the board?

More generally, what types of connectors/terminals are usually used in such applications? What is the best way to go about finding such stuff out?

Comment: I don't see the need for any, isn't that a terminal block to take bare wires?

Comment: @hobbs really new to all this ... if it takes bare wires, how are they fixed onto the terminal so they don't slip out?

Comment: Did they actually name the product "CAN Shield"? That's a remarkably stupid product name! "Why on earth does he want to connect CAN High and CAN Low to CAN Shield?" I thought. All 3 being ISO standardized signal names. Notably, this board doesn't follow the standardized pin-out either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which types of connectors do I need to buy and then crimp to the end of my cables in order to make this connection?

None, the terminal is a board-to-wire connector without a cable part. It is a spring-based connector so it is intended for naked wires with insulation stripped. You can strip the cables with a plain wire cutter (or if professional, by using a stripping tool). The orange part on top is pressed down with a screwdriver to open up the connector temporarily while you attach the wire.